# Selecting in expression features with line break

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, string

I'm trying to filter features in a QGIS layer to those with the following in their `"description"` attribute.

```html
<td>CC_W</td>

<td>3</td>
```

I think what I need is something like this, with the appropriate escape sequences replacing LINEBREAK,LINEBREAK:

`"description" LIKE '%CC_W</td>`LINEBREAK,LINEBREAK`<td>3%'`

I've tried `\r` and `\n` to no avail. Both of them generate no filter hits even when I search them alone over my feature set, which definitely does have line breaks in the "description" attributes.

`"description" LIKE '%\r%'` 0 hits

`"description" LIKE '%\n%'` 0 hits

Comment: Tilde doesn't work. `"description" LIKE '%~%'` 0 hits.

Comment: I got a parse error for that. `"description" ~ '%\n%'`

Comment: `txt  LIKE '%\n%'` works for me, after copy-pasting the sample data from the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression `"description" ~ '\n'`

[image: example]